# Make code wait for popup to open, then scrape the popup

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JS script that automates some browser actions.

With `get_baskets_onclicks`, I am collecting onclick functions from certain DOM elements and returning them in an array. Each onclick looks something like this:

```
onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:"j_id_32:GenerationTable:0:j_id_1e_2_3p",u:"@widgetVar(GenerationCodingDialog)",onco:function(xhr,status,args){PF('GenerationCodingDialog').show();}});return false;"
```

and opens a pop-up from which I need to collect some data with `get_MAP_data`.

Also, each of these functions is called from within `get_MAP_data`.

The problem is I cannot make the code wait for the popup to be opened, so the data returned by `get_MAP_data` is empty.

Besides the below `document.readyState === 'complete'`, I have also tried `window.onload = function(){}`, to no avail.

Is there any way to make the browser (Chrome) wait? I guess I cannot use jQuery, because this is not my webpage.

```
function get_baskets_onclicks() {
    // returns array of functions that launch MAP dialogs
    var baskets = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("ui-commandlink ui-widget margin-right-5px"));
    var baskets_onclicks = baskets.map(basket => basket.onclick);
    return baskets_onclicks;
};

function get_MAP_data(basket_onclick) {
    basket_onclick()
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        console.log("PAGE LOADED");
        // wait here for the dialog to open
        // dt = detail table
        var MAP_data = {} // container for transaction details
        var labels_to_get = ['Description', 'Category', 'Department', 'Justification', 'My Shop Voucher', 'My Shop Coding'];
        var all_dts = document.getElementsByClassName('summary-details-grid');
        var dt = Array.from(all_dts).filter(table => table.parentElement.id == "paymentGenerationmyShopCodingForm")[0];
        var dt_body = dt.children[0];
        var dt_trs = Array.from(dt_body.children)   ;
        dt_trs.forEach(function(tr) {
            tds = Array.from(tr.children);
            tds.forEach(function(td) {
                var label = td.textContent;
                if (labels_to_get.includes(label)) {
                    var value_for_label = tds[1].textContent;
                    MAP_data[label] = value_for_label;
                    console.log(label, value_for_label);
                };
            });
        });
        // console.log(MAP_data);
        return MAP_data;
    };
};

var first_onclick = get_baskets_onclicks()[0];
get_MAP_data(first_onclick);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small, hacky fix would be to make your code poll for the existence of the elements you are checking.

```
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  var all_dts = document.getElementsByClassName('summary-details-grid');
  if (all_dts.length !== 0) {
    // Found some elements, now lets run the code
    clearInterval(interval);
    get_MAP_data(first_onclick);
  }
}, 100);
```

This would check for `summary-details-grid` classes ever 10th of a second, and when it finds them, run your code.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/window.setTimeout

http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setInterval.html

combination of retries, setTimeout, setInterval, while loop, I'm not sure the best way for your specific modal, but one of those options should be fit for polling the DOM results until something is there or it's tried to many times.